# Как правильно именовать CSS классы по BEM на примере?

Tags: html, css, бэм

Для примера накидал шаблон вывода новостей.

1. Как Вы именовали бы классы на предоставленном примере в рамках BEM?
2. Грамотно ли использовать ul списки в моем примере? Или здесь лучше div использовать?

Комментарии в шаблоне написал для наглядности.

```
<!-- главный блок с новостями -->
<div class="news">

    <!-- контейнер с новостями -->
    <ul class="list">

        <!-- колонка с новостью -->
        <li class="column">

            <!-- контейнер с новостью -->
            <ul class="list">

                <!-- заголовок новости -->
                <li class="title">Заголовок новости</li>

                <!-- дата новости -->
                <li class="date">
                    <span class="time">10:00</span>
                    <span class="date">01.01.2000</span>
                </li>

                <!-- описание новости -->
                <li class="description">Описание новости</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84579/discussion-between-andreymal-and-artem-gorlachev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:
В данной разметке два блока:
news - блок новостей;
onenews - блок одной новости

```
<div class="news">
    <ul class="news_list">
        <li class="news_column">
            <!-- Одна новость это отдельный блок (по БЭМ) --> 
            <ul class="onenews">
                <!-- заголовок новости -->
                <li class="onenews_title">Заголовок новости</li>
                <!-- дата новости -->
                <li class="onenews_datetime">
                    <span class="onenews_time">10:00</span>
                    <span class="onenews_date">01.01.2000</span>
                </li>
                <!-- описание новости -->
                <li class="onenews_description">Описание новости</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Для БЭМа нет разницы ul или div.

Comment: А сеошник то здесь причем?

Comment: Один из плюсов БЭМа как раз и заключается в том, что не важно какой html тэг мы используем для верстки. В любой момент времени тэги можно менять и это вообще не повлияет на верстку, потому что БЭМ запрещает описывать css-стили по наименованиям html тэгов. SEOшник один из кандидатов который будет менять тэги в вашей верстке.

Comment: Я не совсем то имел ввиду. Когда я спрашивал про ul, то хотел узнать, на сколько разумно использовать столько ul в моем примере?

Comment: Классы onenews_title, onenews_datetime, onenews_description, я бы однозначно сделал div. Потому что список подразумевает набор однотипных элементов. Если мы это принимаем, тогда onenews тоже div. Далее список колонок тоже так себе список. В итоге я бы сверстал divами.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!